# Gatling how to use the .replace function

Tags: gatling

I want to strip a string from all

```
<br>
```

using i.e.

```
  str.replace("<br/>", "")
```

But I cannot figure out to define this in Gatling. I have googled it a lot and cannot understand if I need to use an .exec and/or a local variable.

Anyone has a concrete example from Gatling doing such a stripping av a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace method of the Scala string class, just make sure that `yourBody` is a String

```
val requestToRemoveBRfromBody= exec(http("Request_1")                                                                        
.post("/yourUrl").body(StringBody(yourBody.replace("/<br>","")))
```